# Use proxy inside a Docker container

Tags: docker, http-proxy

My host server need a proxy to talk to the outside world. It's defined in env like `http_proxy=http://10.10.123.123:8080 https_proxy=http://10.10.123.123:8080`. 
I run an image `tensorflow/tensorflow`, container named `tf1`.

Inside `tf1`(by exec into the container), I would like to install some package like grpcio and tensorflow-serving-api with pip, but fail with network error.

How can I use the proxy of the host inside the container? I have tried exec with `-e` option but fail because of low version docker, so I don't know whether it works.

OS: CentOS 7.2, Docker:1.12.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Helped for me to export the proxy settings in the same `RUN` instruction just before the `apt-get` in `Dockerfile`

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN export "http_proxy=http://host:port" \
    && export "https_proxy=http://host:port" \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y SOME-PACKAGE
```

After that Ubuntu system in container was able to install the packages.

The noted way makes the proxy **available only for this `RUN` instruction**.

If the whole image should use the proxy the `ENV` instruction should be used:

```
FROM ubuntu

ENV http_proxy http://host:port
ENV https_proxy http://host:port

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y SOME-PACKAGE

ENTRYPOINT [ "printenv" ]
```

Building the image `$ docker image build -t test .` and running the container `$ docker run test` will show that the proxy persist

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=8513fc1fb635
http_proxy=http://host:port
https_proxy=http://host:port
HOME=/root
```

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation for working with proxies is to install a tool that transparently routes all traffic to the proxy. 
A popular tool for Linux is [redsocks](http://darkk.net.ru/redsocks/).

Redsocks can be installed on the host as illustrated [here](https://crosp.net/blog/administration/install-configure-redsocks-proxy-centos-linux/).
There is also a [docker image to get redsocks](https://hub.docker.com/r/munkyboy/redsocks/) in case you don't want to install it manually.

Once you install redsocks, all traffic from your host or containers will be redirected to the proxy and you don't need any more to configure proxy env variables.

Answer (score 1):

You can use docker-proxy for using host proxy inside container from https://github.com/silarsis/docker-proxy

Comment: Its Instructions for Use say
_First check out the code then build with: `sudo docker build -t docker-proxy .` Then run with: `./run.sh`._ But how to build the image `FROM ubuntu:14.04` if it need `apt-get update` etc commands but proxy is not established yet? If to download the built image from https://github.com/silarsis/docker-proxy --- how to start it properly? That's not clear.

Comment: BTW, I'm not sure that this works for Windows host machines